# Add Context for redirect in RabbitMQ Management

Tags: rabbitmq

I have RabbitMQ setup on one Windows server and I am trying to set it up the same way on the other server. I did an `Export` then `Import definitions` from the older server but it seems to be missing one item....

In the RabbitMQ Management webpage, on the Overview tab, there is a `Web context -> Context section`. On my old server, I have entries for "RabbitMQ Management" and "Redirect to port XXXX". On the new server, I only have "RabbitMQ Management".

How do I go about adding the "Redirect to port XXXX" context entry? I don't seem to have an option to add or edit contexts in the UI.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out there was a reason I couldn't figure out how to do this, this functionality was added when they were migrating from an older version of RabbitMQ using one port to a new version using the current port. This feature has been removed from the current version of RabbitMQ completely.